# Second function is not changing the value of my button

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to toggle a Table of Contents. I can get the ToC to toggle correctly, but I want to run a second function to change the text of my button to reflect what's on the page. If the ToC is hidden, the button should say "show", and if the ToC is shown, the button should say "hide."

Here is the html relevant to the javascript functions:

```
<div id="toggle_button">
<input type="button" value="Show the Table of Contents" onclick="toggle(); changeButton();"></input>
</div>
```

And here is the javascript (called from a separate document):

```
var toggle = function() {
var Table = document.getElementById('ToC');

    if (Table.style.display === 'inline-block' || Table.style.display === '')       
        Table.style.display = 'none';
    else
        Table.style.display = 'inline-block';
};

var changeButton = function() {
var elem = document.getElementById("toggle_button");

    if (elem.value === "Show the Table of Contents")        
        elem.value = "Hide the Table of Contents";
    else
        elem.value = "Show the Table of Contents";
};
```

The first function runs quite nicely, but the second function (changeButton) does nothing. I can't figure out what's wrong.

EDIT:
I ran it in fiddle, so I'm sharing that link here for ya'll - https://jsfiddle.net/a9gd4cjz/

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle..

Comment: Here is everything I'm working with done in fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a9gd4cjz/

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
var elem = document.getElementById("toggle_button");
```

then `elem` is a div, and a div has no `value`.

You probably want

```
var elem = document.querySelector("#toggle_button input[type=button]");
```

Side note: a code with repeated strings is harder to maintain. A solution would be to declare them in variables once.

Answer (score 0):

You are selecting the wrong element by id, you need to assign an id to the input button like so.

```
var changeButton = function() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("my_button_id");

    if (elem.value === "Show the Table of Contents")        
        elem.value = "Hide the Table of Contents";
    else
        elem.value = "Show the Table of Contents";
};
```

---

```
<input id="my_button_id" type="button" value="Show the Table of Contents" onclick="toggle(); changeButton();"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is here:

```
document.getElementById("toggle_button");
```

That's the ID of the div that contains the button, not the button itself.
Try this:

```
<input id="toggle_button" type="button" value="Show the Table of Contents" onclick="toggle(); changeButton();"></input>
```

And remove the id from the div.

Comment: That didn't seem to do the trick. No change in behavior. I still made the change though - might as well fix everything wrong instead of just the root issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong.

Change

```
var elem = document.getElementById("toggle_button");
```

to

```
var elem = document.getElementById("toggle_button").childNodes[0];
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the improved code:

HTML:

```
    <div id="toggle_button_container">
        <button id="toggle_button" class="show" type="button" value="Show the Table of Contents" onclick="toggle(); changeButton();"></button>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    button#toggle_button.show:after {
        content:"Show the Table of Contents";
    }

    button#toggle_button.hide:after {
        content:"Hide the Table of Contents";
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
    function toggle() {
        var Table = document.getElementById('ToC');

        if (Table.style.display === 'inline-block' || Table.style.display === '')       
            Table.style.display = 'none';
        else
            Table.style.display = 'inline-block';
    }

    function changeButton() {
        var elem = document.getElementById("toggle_button");

        if (elem.className == "show")        
            elem.className ="hide";
        else
            elem.className ="show";
    }
```

And, if you are using this code, forget my first answer.

CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dYPmzP

Comment: I added that, but it didn't do anything. What is ".childNodes[0]"? What is supposed to do?

Comment: childNode give an array of children DOM elements, and [0] means the first one (the only one in your case).

Comment: and, if you noticed, I added new code that should definitely work.